# How to read XML content in browser using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I have a link, clicking on which will open a new browser with only XML content in it.
I need to verify certain tags in this XML.

Please let me know how do I do it.

Tried getBodyText, getHtmlSource and getText - Nothing helps...!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: By opening you mean new browser window? If yes, you should change current window to new one.

Comment: @p0deje: Yes a new browser window... I do switch to the new window but getting the text(in plain format or XML format) is not possible...

Comment: It should be noted that you don't need to use a browser object to retreive XML from a webservice:  you can do it with a simple HTTP post, such as with Apache HTTP utils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download the xml and use a xml parser to parse the xml as per your need.

I am using **jdom**(http://www.jdom.org/) for parsing my xml files.

To understand how IE renders the XML, please go through: -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757841(v=vs.85).aspx

Let me know if you need any further help on this.

Comment: Thanks PD Mohanty. I am able to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the xpaths of the tags you want to verify and then use getText.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source of page with `getPageSource()`. Then you can parse source with any XML processor (not sure which one is the best in Java) and perform assertions for processed XML.